# Android Custom ListView got Error in Fragment Layout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Im trying to create a Custom ListView in a normal activity (got 2 arrays for the listview item).
The MainActivity uses fragmentlayout (im putting in a navigation drawer)

But when i put a CustomListview code and run it, it just force closes and LogCat says "Error in creating fragment".

Here's the customlistview tutorial link :
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/

I traced the error source and it was on the setadapter line. (Eclipse didnt catch that as an error line)

```
ListViewAdapter lviewAdapter;
            lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, berita, truelink);
            lb.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
            lb.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

This is the layout part :

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/daftarberita"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Can anyone kindly help me solve this ?

LogCat :

04-09 13:54:28.720: I/Adreno-EGL(736): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL

04-09 13:54:28.720: I/Adreno-EGL(736): Build Date: 11/04/13 Mon
04-09 13:54:28.720: I/Adreno-EGL(736): Local Branch: 
04-09 13:54:28.720: I/Adreno-EGL(736): Remote Branch: 
04-09 13:54:28.720: I/Adreno-EGL(736): Local Patches: 
04-09 13:54:28.720: I/Adreno-EGL(736): Reconstruct Branch: 
04-09 13:54:29.011: D/OpenGLRenderer(736): Enabling debug mode 0

04-09 13:54:31.273: D/dalvikvm(736): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3962K, 27% free 18563K/25304K, paused 8ms, total 8ms

04-09 13:54:31.513: I/System.out(736): SAMAPAI SINIII

04-09 13:54:31.523: E/MainActivity(736): Error in creating fragment

04-09 13:54:32.314: D/dalvikvm(736): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 921K, 10% free 22986K/25304K, paused 12ms, total 12ms

Comment: where is your logcat??? post it

Comment: @Dede we cant help unless there logcat error log

Comment: ah sry mybad , I will post it

Comment: can you please post fragment code where used ListView?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom ListView, then why are you using the Android ListView on the layout xml file?

it should be:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <my.package.name.MyListView
                android:id="@+id/daftarberita"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </my.package.name.MyListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The customlistview idea was based on the tutorial from :
 http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/

so i was just blindly followed it. (since this is my first time trying to create custom listview in fragment layout)

Comment: either way i'll try ur solution. Thx for it